# qt - decimals and round up to whole numbers

Tags: c++, qt

This is what I've got so far but I can't figure out my next steps.

When I divide my value with 3 I get whole numbers but I want it to display with one decimal and I don't know how.

When that's done I want to round the decimal up or down depending on its value. If it's 3.5 or over it should become 4 and if it's 3.4 or under it should be 3.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){

int paragraph = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
int section = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt();
int lines = ui->lineEdit_3->text().toInt();

int sum = (paragraph * (lines + 1) -(section * lines));

ui->label_4->setText(QString::number(sum/3));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are dividing integrers and therefore get integer. So fractional part is truncated.

```
int a = 11;
a = a / 3;        // a is 3 now

double b = 11;
b = b / 3;        // b is 3.6666... now

double c = a / 3; // c is 3 now
c = b / 3;        // c is 3.6666... now
```

Return type of operators like `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` is determined by first object in there.

Just use `qRound(double(sum)/3.0)` or `qRound(double(sum)/3)` to get rounded value.

If you want to display result with 1 decimal, use `QString::number(double(sum)/3.0, 'f', 1)`.

Please study C basics (read critical parts of [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)) before using C++. And study C++ before using Qt.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round up and down you can use the C++ math functions `ceil` and `floor`. `ceil` rounds up, and `floor` rounds down.

For the display you can specify `QString::number(sum/3, 'f', 1)` which specifies your number, the display format argument (there's an explanation of that [here on the QString docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#argument-formats)) and then finally sets 2 for the precision.

Comment: i figured out the display for my decimals as you showed, but at the ceil and floor im lost. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, `int roundedUp = ceil(4.2); int roundedDown = floor(4.2);`

Comment: and `double(sum)/3` ofc